# Cnames and ssl - ok if both names have ssl?

Tags: ssl, https, dns, cname, http-redirect

Not sure if it's best to ask here or over at serverfault. But if I used a cname to point https://www.example.com to https://www.domain.com would the browser still throw an error about example.com  pretending to be domain.com? Is there anyway around this that anyone knows of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your browser will throw an error, unless you have the secondary name also embedded in the certificate as a "Subject Alternate Name".